# What is the exact condition of touchdown in American football?

Tags: rules, american-football, scoring

I wonder how the 'touchdown' is defined in American football.
Specifically, I would like to know whether the ball should complete go through the end line which is 6 feet wide.

In soccer, the ball should complete go through the end line to be considered a goal. Is it the same as in American football?
Should the ball touch the ground, or is it okay the ball stay in the air?

Comment: Is there a specific aspect of [Rule 11, Section 2](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2022-nfl-rulebook/#rule11) you are not sure about? Or is it simply not something you have looked at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ball does not have to be completely gone through the plane of the goal line.
According to the NFL Official Rulebook as of 2022. Rule 11 Scoring, Section 2 - Touchdown, the ball is "on", "above", or behine the plane of the goald line to be considered a touchdown.